# How automatically sort the array after each input in excel

Tags: excel

How to do this in `excel`, when you enter a list into a given row say `row_1`, and you will automatically obtain a sorted list e.g as long as you input

```
R1 : 2, 4, 5, 1
```

you immediately get:

```
R1 : 1, 2, 4, 5
```

note that, not manually sort after input, and not use `VBA.`

Answer (score 0):

The only way that this can be done is by using a **macro** that is triggered whenever something new is entered in the worksheet. You can, for instance, add a macro to the code for a worksheet that is triggered when something in the worksheet changes. (You can view the code window by right-clicking the worksheet tab and choosing View Code from the resulting Context menu.) The following is an example of one such simple macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Resume Next
    EnableEvents = False

    Range("A1").Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), _
      Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
      OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

   EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to add `EnableEvents = False` or you will create an infinite loops of events (and set  `EnableEvents = True` at the end)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @chrisneilsen. Updated the asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below formula in `Row 2`,

`=IFERROR(SMALL(1:1,COLUMN()),"")`

When you enter the formula, select the `Row 2` completely and enter the formula in formula area and press `CTRL` + `ENTER`.
This applies the formula to each and every cell in `Row 2`. Whenever you enter a new value in `Row 1`, the `Row 2` represents it in a sorted order. Let me know if you need anything else.